# Upsert in KnexJS

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have an upsert query in PostgreSQL like:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (id, name)
values
  (1, 'Gabbar')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET
  name = 'Gabbar'
WHERE
  table.id = 1
```

I need to use knex to this upsert query. How to go about this?

Comment: maybe the best way is 2 queries : first select if date does exists, then if not insert your data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I solved this using the following suggestion from [Dotnil's answer on Knex Issues Page](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/701):

```
var data = {id: 1, name: 'Gabbar'};
var insert = knex('table').insert(data);
var dataClone = {id: 1, name: 'Gabbar'};

delete dataClone.id;

var update = knex('table').update(dataClone).whereRaw('table.id = ' + data.id);
var query = `${ insert.toString() } ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET ${ update.toString().replace(/^update\s.*\sset\s/i, '') }`;

return knex.raw(query)
.then(function(dbRes){
  // stuff
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: From @HasFiveVowels link they talk a lot about how using toString method won't help preventing sql injections.
I'm wondering if the formatted string is any different? Otherwise you might consider making a better switch or updating your answer.

Comment: Will this work for array of objects to be inserted?

Answer (score 17):

As of `knex@v0.21.10`+ a new method `onConflict` was introduced.

[Official documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-onConflict) says:

> Implemented for the PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite databases. A
> modifier for insert queries that specifies alternative behaviour in
> the case of a conflict. A conflict occurs when a table has a PRIMARY
> KEY or a UNIQUE index on a column (or a composite index on a set of
> columns) and a row being inserted has the same value as a row which
> already exists in the table in those column(s). The default behaviour
> in case of conflict is to raise an error and abort the query. Using
> this method you can change this behaviour to either silently ignore
> the error by using .onConflict().ignore() or to update the existing
> row with new data (perform an "UPSERT") by using
> .onConflict().merge().

So in your case, the implementation would be:

```
knex('table')
  .insert({
    id: id,
    name: name
  })
  .onConflict('id')
  .merge()
```

Answer (score 8):

I've created a function for doing this and [described it on the knex github issues page](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/54#issuecomment-294271255) (along with some of the gotchas for dealing with composite unique indices).

```js
const upsert = (params) => {
  const {table, object, constraint} = params;
  const insert = knex(table).insert(object);
  const update = knex.queryBuilder().update(object);
  return knex.raw(`? ON CONFLICT ${constraint} DO ? returning *`, [insert, update]).get('rows').get(0);
};
```

Example usage:

```js
const objToUpsert = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

upsert({
    table: 'test',
    object: objToUpsert,
    constraint: '(a, b)',
})
```

#### A note about composite nullable indices

If you have a composite index (a,b) and b is nullable, then values (1, NULL) and (1, NULL) are considered mutually unique by Postgres (I don't get it either).

Comment: While your link really helps, it would be better if you shared an answer here too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach I could think of!

```
exports.upsert = (t, tableName, columnsToRetain, conflictOn) => {
    const insert = knex(tableName)
        .insert(t)
        .toString();
    const update = knex(tableName)
        .update(t)
        .toString();
    const keepValues = columnsToRetain.map((c) => `"${c}"=${tableName}."${c}"`).join(',');
    const conflictColumns = conflictOn.map((c) => `"${c.toString()}"`).join(',');
    let insertOrUpdateQuery = `${insert} ON CONFLICT( ${conflictColumns}) DO ${update}`;
    insertOrUpdateQuery = keepValues ? `${insertOrUpdateQuery}, ${keepValues}` : insertOrUpdateQuery;
    insertOrUpdateQuery = insertOrUpdateQuery.replace(`update "${tableName}"`, 'update');
    insertOrUpdateQuery = insertOrUpdateQuery.replace(`"${tableName}"`, tableName);
    return Promise.resolve(knex.raw(insertOrUpdateQuery));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

very simple.

Adding onto Dorad's answer, you can choose specific columns to upsert using merge keyword.

```
knex('table')
  .insert({
    id: id,
    name: name
  })
  .onConflict('id')
  .merge(['name']); // put column names inside an array which you want to merge.
```